# Boolean MySQL field always return "true" in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a very puzzling situation that I still cannot resolve. Hope someone knows what am I doing wrong.

Situation:

- I have a MySQL table. It has some fields for flags (true/false) values. These fields are defined as BIT in MySQL (at least, PHPMyAdmin reports so). A browse to the table shows that the data has different values in these fields (0s and 1s).
- I'm connecting with a C# WPF desktop application, using MySQL library.
- I'm using a MySQLDataReader (let's call it "MyReader").

The program works, and it retrieves the data from the database. Everything seems ok. But then, when I reviewed the data with more detail and applied filters, I found that all the boolean fields appear as "true".

If I try this:

- `bool MyValue = (bool)MyReader["Field"];`

it crashes (Invalid cast exception).
However:

- `bool MyValue = Convert.ToBoolean(MyReader["Field"]);`

works. But the returned value IS ALWAYS "TRUE", no matter which value is in the database table.

I found that BIT datatypes from MySQL traslate as SByte to C#, so I tried:

- `SByte MyValue = Convert.ToSByte(MyReader["Field"]);`

Again, it works. And again, the value is always "1".
If I try to cast directly:

- `SByte MyValue = (SByte)MyReader["Field"];`

I also get an Invalid Cast exception.

Then I tried:

- `int MyValue = Convert.ToInt32(MyReader["Field"]);`

And again, it works, but the returned value is always 1.

So, I ran out of ideas. I cannot find a way to get the actual value of those fields, C# always returns '1' (or 'true', if I try to convert to Boolean) regardless of the field value. The table has other fields (numbers, strings, dates and so on), and all of them are correctly displayed, only bool (bit) values are incorrect.

I'm thinking about changing the tables and defining those fields as "int" instead of bit. However, there are other applications that use the data and it would imply vast code corrections, so this is not really feasible.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what query are you executing to get the data which is then accessed via DataReader ?

Comment: BIT is not really a boolean or toggle type as you think, see the [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-type.html) doc, it is to binary digits of certain length.

Comment: Which MySQL client library are you using? MySql.Data or MySqlConnector? The former might have type conversion bugs related to BIT, e.g., https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=97067.

Comment: What does "when I reviewed the data with more detail and applied filters" mean? Did you change the SQL being executed? If the code worked before that change, but doesn't afterwards, it could mean that that change introduced the bug. Please show your code.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran its a plain SELECT, other fields of the query are as expected, only the boolean fields are always true. Thanks for the link, I'll check it, it is very possible to be a data conversion issue.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I'm using MySQL.Data (I will check your link, thanks). No, I didn't change the query: I fill a DataGrid with the query data and all seems ok, but after reviewing and filtering the data (DataGrid functionality) I found that all the boolean fields have a "true" value (which is not the case). The query is the same and I have tested it in PHPMyAdmin and it works as expected. So, the cause might be a bug in the library as you suggested, thanks.